# Alignment of two pictures

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment

How can I get two pictures perfectly align alongside. My code is given below.

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{3.3cm}
    \centering
    \subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{figa/ParameterSpace}\label{figa}}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}{3.3cm}
    \centering
    \subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.25\textheight]{figa/StringMotion}\label{figb}}
\end{minipage}
\mycaption[Motion of open string in spacetime.]{%
  (a) Parameter space for open strings.
  (b) Open string worlsheet in target space.}
\label{figA}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: from your code snippet follows that your equation should be aligned as you wish. to say more, we should see complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` preamble with to image related packages and end with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Does changing `\begin{minipage}{3.3cm}` to `\begin{minipage}[t]{3.3cm}` help? And why do you squeeze the pictures in minipages of fixed width? (No wonder that the pictures overlap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of putting the sub-figures inside `minipage`s is the problem here. The blocks created by the `minipage`s are too narrow for the images to fit, so they overlap. Drop the use of `minipage`s entirely:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
%  \begin{minipage}{3.3cm}
%    \centering
    \subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}}
%  \end{minipage}
  \hspace{0.5cm}
%  \begin{minipage}{3.3cm}
%    \centering
    \subtop[]{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-b}}
%  \end{minipage}
  \caption[Motion of open string in spacetime.]{%
    (a) Parameter space for open strings.
    (b) Open string worlsheet in target space.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```